# Site Column in Content Type Hub is not visible in subscriber site collection

Tags: content-type, site-collection, site, site-column, content-type-hub

I have created Site Column say "mycolumn" in my Content Type Hub and associated a content type -say myCT - and this content type is published and ran the 2 timer jobs.Though the content type is visible in subscriber site collection,the  column "mycolumn" is not visible in Subscriber Site Collection. am surprised and  not able to understand why its not visible in my subscriber site's site columns gallery.This is happening on my  Production Environment.In my staging  environment  this works perfectly.

Comment: you can check the error log list at the destination site collection: /Lists/ContentTypeSyncLog

Comment: Is the column a Lookup?